# Get pack uri of a type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to get the pack uri or physical path of a type?

For example a type named IdUil part of an assembly named CommonUtil return something like

> CommonUtil;component/UserUtil/IdUtil.cs

The aim is to load resource dictionary which exist in the same path. In this case, CommonUtil/UserUtil/IdUtil.xaml

For some reason, I can't rely on the namespace name of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pack URI doesn't refer to a type, it refers to a *resource*. And of course you need to know where this resource is actually defined to be able to use it in the first place. This is what the pack URI actually specifies.

From where/what are you supposed to get the pack URI if you don't have any kind of reference to the resource?

Once you know the name of resource, e.g. "UserUtil/IdUtil.png", you could easily build a pack URI yourself using simple string concatenation.

Comment: Does that also mean there is no way to get the path of a type within the assembly?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a path of a type".